# parseJSON to JSON rsponse in jquery-ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am new to AJAX using jquery. I have a json response as below:

```
[{"customer_name":"Customer A"},{"customer_name":"Customer B"},{"customer_name":"Customer C"}]
```

And my ajax file is :

```
 function(result){
    $('#resdiv').html(result);
    console.log(result);
    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(result);//parse JSON
    alert(json_obj);

    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in json_obj)
    {
    output+="<li>" + json_obj[i].customer_name + "</li>";
    }
    output+="</ul>";
    $('#resdiv1').html(output);
}
```

Though I can view the JSON response in div id `resdiv`, the div id `resdiv1` is empty ! Also `alert(json_obj);` does not alerts anything ! Whats wrong with the file ?

NB: I am learning from [Zuch Tutorial](https://gist.github.com/zuch/3720842)

Comment: when your function is called?????

Comment: @rajeshkakawat it was called on `clicl()`.it was ok i think since the `alert(result)` is coming

Comment: is result string or json array?

Comment: its `json_array`. Check my question , the the json response is given

Comment: if it is json not a string don't parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to parse the json again.Simply do a iteration and try like this

```
var json = [{"customer_name":"Customer A"},{"customer_name":"Customer B"},{"customer_name":"Customer C"}];

var output="<ul>";
$.each(json,function(key,val){
  output+="<li>" + val.customer_name + "</li>";
});
output+="</ul>";

console.log(output);
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OfiYINa/1/edit)**

Comment: HI @User016 thanks but still I am not able to view the response !

Comment: Have you checked the demo fiddle

Comment: Yes,but I see only a blue screen in the output section !

Comment: Check the console in the fiddle and run the code to see the o/p in console

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```
// Need to parse if string.
var result = '[{"customer_name":"Customer A"},{"customer_name":"Customer B"},{"customer_name":"Customer C"}]';
var json_obj = $.parseJSON(result);//parse JSON

// No need to parse
var json_obj = [{"customer_name":"Customer A"},{"customer_name":"Customer B"},{"customer_name":"Customer C"}];
```

Also check this

```
// if undefined, you don't have resdiv1 div or you have call function before your div render.
alert($('#resdiv1').html());
```

Comment: Thanks rajesh for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
   function(result){ 
      $('#resdiv').html(result); 
      console.log(result); 
      var json_obj = $.parseJSON(result);
      //parse JSON alert(json_obj);

      var output="<ul>"; 
       $.each(json_obj,function(key,val){ 
           output+="<li>" + val.customer_name + "</li>"; 
           console.log(key+":::"+val);
      });
        output+="</ul>";

     $('#resdiv1').html(output); 
  }
```

Comment: added console.log can check the console response